# Is there a Cassandra demo database in form of create and populate .cql scripts?

Tags: cassandra, cql

**Context**

I had set up and Cassandra database for project POC, all is OK.
I've googled for Cassandra demo database in form of create and populate .cql scripts with no result.

**Question**

Is there a Cassandra demo database in form of create and populate .cql scripts? (...so I can simply run them with cqlsh with no further dependencies...) or a Python script would be also do it, I can find out the driver dependencies.

Any ideas, how to set up with minimal effort a sample db with sample data?

Answer (score 3):

I'm not aware of anything official, but I built some of this for the Cassandra chapter in [Seven NoSQL Databases in a Week](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B07CDDKNXF).  There's a CQL file in my Git repo, here: https://github.com/aploetz/packt

If you download/clone it, the `astronauts_table.cql` file does all the work.  You may need to adjust the `COPY` statements at the bottom, to make sure that they're pointing to the correct location of the `astronauts.csv` file (which is also in the repo).

Running the file should work (depending on your `PATH`) something like this:

```
cqlsh -u username -p yourpassword -f ~/Documents/workspace/packt/astronauts_table.cql
```